# Tradingview - Pine Script show Take profit and Stop loss on the chart

Tags: pine-script

I try to create my first backtest in Pine Script based on Take Profit and Stop Loss. I find really useful to see on the chart when a position hit the TP or the SL.

So far I only found solutions which shows only when the script exists the position without show if it was TP or SL. I want to visualize on the chart only the TP if the price hit the TP and only the SL if the price hit the SL.

This is a buy only sample script where I failed to achieve what I want. In this script the SL condition is not working. It works only if both TP and SL are specified in the same strategy.exit() command, but this way I only have to possibility to write on the chart the "exit" and I could not find a way to write only TP or only SL.

```
/@version=5
strategy("v1 ADA HMA20", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000, default_qty_value=100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, commission_value=0.1)

// STEP 1:
// Make inputs that set the take profit % (optional)
longProfitPerc = input.float(title="Long Take Profit (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
shortProfitPerc = input.float(title="Short Take Profit (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01

// Set stop loss level with input options (optional)
longLossPerc = input.float(title="Long Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
shortLossPerc = input.float(title="Short Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01

// Calculate moving averages
HMAtrend = ta.roc(ta.hma(close,20),1)
HMA = ta.hma(close,20)

// Calculate trading conditions
//buy_condition1 = ta.roc(ta.hma(close,20),1) > 0
//buy_condition2 = close > ta.hma(close,20)
enterLong = (ta.roc(ta.hma(close,20),1) > 0) and (close > ta.hma(close,20))

// Plot moving averages
plot(series=HMA, color=color.blue)

// STEP 2:
// Figure out take profit price
longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)
// Determine stop loss price
longStopPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - longLossPerc)
shortStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + shortLossPerc)

// Submit entry orders
if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
//if (enterShort)
//    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)

// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders based on take profit price
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("TP Buy", limit=longExitPrice)
//if (strategy.position_size < 0)
//    strategy.exit(id="TP Sell", limit=shortExitPrice)

// Submit exit orders based on calculated stop loss price
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("SL Buy","Buy", stop=longStopPrice)
//if (strategy.position_size < 0)
//    strategy.exit(id="SL Sell", stop=shortStopPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already calculate the levels. So you can just plot them as well.

```
inTrade = strategy.position_size > 0

plot(inTrade ? longExitPrice : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles)
plot(inTrade ? longStopPrice : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles)
```

Comment: How can I plot to the chart only the SL if it hits the SL and only the TP if it hits the TP value?